# Strategies in protecting your SSH keys in case of laptop theft

Tags: ssh, security, privacy, anti-theft

Is there any cool tool that encrypts your ssh keys and locks it down when you shutdown or put your computer to sleep?

So in case someone steals your laptop, they can't get into your servers etc.?

Comment: SSH keys **without** a passphrase?

Comment: how about setting the lifetime for your keys in the ssh agent to 0?

Comment: What OS is that? For both Linux and Windows/cygwin, my .ssh dir points to another dir in a crypted image/volume.

Comment: Mac OSX (latest)

Answer (score 0):

If you are on *nix

The ssh agent is controled by the user using the command **ssh-add** The agent asks the user for password and manages how long a socket stays open and where the keys gets stored using *$SSH_AUTH_SOCK* variable

You can for example lock the agent with

```
ssh-add -x
```

maybe you can execute this commands before the computer shutdown or sleep
and unlock the agent with

```
 ssh-add -X
```

an other way would be to set the lifetime of keys used by the agent to limited time like this:

```
ssh-add -t seconds
```